# SQL - Changing Stored img URL in SQL db to local file path

Tags: html, sql, asp.net, sql-server, blob

I have image URLs stored in my SQL database, but the source of the images has not been reliable recently and causing long load time on my pages. The contents of my database update regularly. Is there a method I can use to store the images locally and display the images on my page via my server file path? Most of the images or over 1 MB so I was told not to store them in SQL directly as a blob. I am using ASP, HTML, SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this: Create a Column to store path to pictures.
[image]

Then in the ImagePath enter: For each image/images

```
C:Users/JohnDoe/Documents/Pictures/SQLimages/JohnDoe.jpg
```

Update !!!
Save the images in your chosen Directory for Example.
 Currently Your Table might look like this:

```
ID            ImagePath
---------------------------------
1             \\fakeURL\image111
2             \\fakeURL\image222
3             \\fakeURL\image333
4             \\fakeURL\image444
```

Once you have saved your images to chosen local folder you can run this script

```
UPDATE dbo.yourDatabase
SET Value = REPLACE(Value, '\fakeURL\', '')
WHERE ID <=100000 --arbitrary number can be any number
```

This will replace the current URL path to your local path(You won't have to manually enter path name).

Comment: I have the URLs stored, so using this I would have to manually save each picture and add the filepath.  I have thousands of records

Comment: Unfortunately, you will have to provide the data(path of Image). If you are going to save the pictures locally then the path will change and you will need to change the path. You can write a query to update the reference to images. Very hard to answer your question without looking at how you have structured your table.

Comment: The setup is very basic, just assume I have a column called imgurl with the web URL to the image, and a filepath column i want to save and store the local file path to

Comment: I have updated my answer hope it helps you achieve your goal.